# How do I build a Model to represent a list of records retrieved from EF and follow DRY?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have an EF database where I have a model called **Foo** and that has several attributes one of which is *Title*.  In my Home view, I want to display a list of nested Foo's grouped by Title.  So the display might look like

```
Title 1
  ID 1
  ID 2
  ID 3

Title 2
  ID 4
  ID 5
  ID 6
```

With Linq, getting that data is easy enough.

```
var foos = myDbContext.Foos.GroupBy(x => x.Title)().ToList();
```

If I examine foos.First().Key that will return the "grouped by" Title, and foos.First().ToList() will return a list of Foos for the first "grouped" title.  Should I create a model like the following and then in my Razor delcare model to be `@model List<Models.HomeViewModel>`

```
public class HomeViewModel
{
    public String Title { get; set; }
    public List<Foo> Foos{ get; set; }
}
```

And then in my controller use linq to transform **foos** to the model?

```
var model = rc.Select(x=> new HomeViewModel(){Title=x.Key, Foos = x.ToList()}).ToList();
return View(model);
```